# RadAjaxManagerProxy on programmatically created usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radajaxloadingpanel

**Situation:**

I have created a custom webusercontrol. The user control is fully created in code .

It consists of a radgrid and radcombox.

The radcombox is filled with database tables, when the user select a table the data
needs to be shown in the radgrid.

This usercontrol is added to a aspx page. Everything works perfectly.

**Here comes the problem:**

I want a radajaxloadingpanel to be shown on the radgrid while it rebinds, using a radajaxmanagerproxy control. This **doesn't work** until I **hit** the **refresh** button or a **page next** or **prev** of the **radgrid**. Then everything **works fine**.

I know the combobox works because the data does change only the loadingpanel isn't shown.

Does anybody have a clue on how to solve this, a work around or a suggestion I can look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work. I did something wrong in the creation life cicle:

now i have it like this. And it works ;)

```
   public class CustumControl
     implements CompositeControl

     Private RadAjaxLoadingPanel1 As New RadAjaxLoadingPanel
     Private RadAjaxManagerProxy1 As New RadAjaxManagerProxy
      ....
      Protected Sub Control_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
          Me.Controls.Add(RadAjaxLoadingPanel1)
          Me.Controls.Add(RadAjaxManagerProxy1)

          With RadAjaxManagerProxy1.AjaxSettings  
               .AddAjaxSetting(...) 
          End with 
      End Sub
      ....

      Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
        'Set properties controls and add themwill
      End Sub
   end class
```

Hope this will help other people with simular problems.

grtz Yuri